# Error in Bluetooth specification? Heading field of Location and Speed

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, specifications

The Location and Speed characteristics in section 3.137 of the [Bluetooth GATT Specification Supplement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gss/) document defines the Heading field (Version Date: 2024-02-21)

It is specified as a `uint16` with a unit multiplier of 10^-7 degrees.
That seems obviously incorrect. A `uint16` has a maximum value of 65535. When multiplied with 10^-7 it gives a maximum of 0.0065535 degrees.

I have found some implementation that uses 10^-2 as multiplier instead. Does anybody know whether that is what it should be?

How do I submit an errata on the specification, if I am not a Bluetooth SIG member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly an error as you suggest. In the [Navigation characteristic](https://bitbucket.org/bluetooth-SIG/public/src/ebd045e68491207a16949c115a70e503ee0671f7/gss/org.bluetooth.characteristic.navigation.yaml#lines-52), Heading is defined as d=-2, just as you've seen. (Errors like this aren't incredibly common, but they certainly exist. I've run into clearly erroneous values before.)

You can [fill out an erratum](https://support.bluetooth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360054449232-File-an-erratum) as a Jira. But I don't believe you can access it without being part of a member company. (Adopter membership is free, but it's really only for companies.)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to fill out an erratum when you are not a member of the SIG. Hopefully somebody who is a member, sees this will do it for us.

Comment: FYI, this issue has now been forwarded to SIG and is now number ES-25136.